# Why do we need a RTOS on ARM Cortex-M

Tags: arm, rtos, cortex-m

If we can already execute C programs on cortex-m like micro-controllers, Why do we even need to install RTOS (or other operating systems).?
What benefits it can provide if micro-controller is intended to be multi-purpose.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An operating system provides a level of abstraction between the code written by an application programmer and the actual hardware the program runs on.
So you don't have to worry, as an application programmer, about the details of the hardware, as they are handled by drivers.
And thus you can compile the same program for many different hardware platforms, if they run the same (or a compatible) operating system.

Comment: Thank you, Do I still need an operating system if my micro-controller is supposed to execute the same code each time it gets an input from a sensor.?

Comment: Do you need multitasking ? using a lot of different devices ? transmitting data over a network ? Storing measurements as files ?

Comment: In few cases yes, But I could also have projects that does not include multi-tasking.

Comment: You don't need an OS to have a HAL.  An OS is much more that a HAL.

Comment: I didn't write "_only_ provides an _hardware_ abstract layer". An OS defines abstract concepts like "file" "thread" "network connection" "signal" etc and provides an API to play with them.

Answer (score 1):

No you dont need an RTOS only if you need/want the features of the (particular) RTOS.  You can program the microcontroller the way you/we always have without one if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Typical things an RTOS might bring,

1. Memory management (who owns memory)
2. Interrupt handling support
3. Scheduling (pre-emptive or co-operative)
4. Usually several drivers in a BSP for your hardware/SOC
5. Debug tools
6. Some sort of shell
7. File systems
8. IPC (inter-process communitation)
9. A tool suite
10. A build environment
11. Memory protection
12. Networking

Your application may or may not need these features depending on your end goal.  Some of them may be detrimental to your organizations work flow (like the tool suite and build environment).  As a product matures, you may end up needing features you didn't account for.

However, a completely custom solution will probably have a smaller foot print.  The race conditions involved in interrupt handling can be quite difficult to get right.  Probably most RTOS will give a better implementation than something custom that evolves over time.  If you are very dedicated, a state machine with polling of devices can be more optimal (hard real time) but again it is difficult to get right.

If the RTOS is BSD (or other permissive) licensed , it maybe possible to reuse the driver code to your own custom infra-structure.  At some point your code may become an 'RTOS' of sorts.  There are [many to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems).

*POSIX* compliance is a common standard.  If you confine your code to *POSIX*, you are portable to many different RTOS/OS.  However, most often an API that is more rich than *POSIX*; it is one way they differentiate each other.  You may be able to use more 3<sup>rd</sup> party libraries if the RTOS is *POSIX* compliant.